# ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [125]]

Tags: ssh, permissions, git, docker, jenkins

Our jenkins deploy process checks out our git repo into the workspace and create the docker container from the docker file.

Docker file is given in the ec2 machine. and commands to create docker container is given in the jenkins.

When building the file I am getting the following error in jenkins:

```
 SSH: Connecting from host [ip-XXXXX.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [docker_host] ...
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [docker_host] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [125]]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Jenkins publish over ssh:

[image]

Docker file in ec2:

[image]

Can someone pls help me on this!

Comment: there's not enough information to help you - probably passing the wrong ssh key or sth

Comment: Check this [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73516569/598141)